# How do i check a specific input?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a small game, and i want to make a input checker.

Now when a user makes a message in my game, i want my game to check the message and if the message is nothing it wont make the message. Instead it will print out this:

```
msg1 = input ("\033[1;34;40mType a message: ")
```

All until the user inputs a message that contains a character or a number.
Now i have made my system of checking the message using functions, but it does not seem to work. It does what i told it to but when the user types something the message is nothing.

Here is my system:

```
def repeatmsg1():
    msg1_ = input ("\033[1;34;40mType a message: ") 
    if msg1 == "":
        msg1check()

    

def msg1check():
    msg1 = input ("\033[1;34;40mType a message: ") 
    if msg1 == "":
        repeatmsg1()


msg1 = input ("\033[1;34;40mType a message: ") 

if msg1 == "" :
    msg1check()
```

Comment: Why is there no `print` in your code?

Comment: What print? Please make an answer.

Comment: Your problem is not returning from the functions. when you define `msg1` inside each of your functions, it is not the same `msg1` you have outside the functions

Comment: Thank you Tomerikoo! It totally answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```py
msg1 = False
while not msg1:
    msg1 = input("\033[1;34;40mType a message: ") 
print (msg1)
```

Comment: I will try, please wait.

Comment: I got this error: IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: so fix the indentation...

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Just remove the spaces (I edited the answer, copy again the code).

Comment: Yes, you fixed it but when i run the game it asks me to type a message, i test it out by putting my message empty and it works. Now another problem shows up. When i type my message it prints it out like this: (username goes here): (message goes here) But when i use your code it prints the message and then the username, not even in the same line.

Comment: so mark the answer as accepted and ask another question.

Comment: I found someone that answered my question much better, thank you on the help!